# Print only odd dictionary keys and their items

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary and I need to print only the ones with odd numbers (1, 3 ...). How would I go about doing that?

```
zen = {
    1: 'Beautiful is better than ugly.',
    2: 'Explicit is better than implicit.',
    3: 'Simple is better than complex.',
    4: 'Complex is better than complicated.',
    5: 'Flat is better than nested.',
    6: 'Sparse is better than dense.',
    7: 'Readability counts.',
    8: 'Special cases aren't special enough to the rules.',
    9: 'Although practicality beats purity.',
   10: 'Errors should never pass silently.'
   }
```

So far I have:

```
for c in zen:
print (c , zen[c][:])
```

Comment: You can do `c % 2` to give you the remainder of `c` divided by `2`, and if `c%2` equals `0` then c must be even.

Comment: The trick here is that since zen is a dictionary, an enumeration of the dictionary will be unordered, so if you want them to be ordered (1, 3, 5...), you'll need to generate the keys yourself.  Try, `for i in range(1,10,2): print(zen[i])`  (And, by the way, the math word for uneven is "odd".)

Comment: @tom10 Wow! We got the same answer at almost the exact same time.

Comment: @teclnol: Well, yours is an answer and mine just a lazy comment (so I gave the answer an upvote).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your keys are numbers:

```
for i in range(1,len(zen),2):
    print(zen[i])
```

It starts at 1, and steps by 2, so it i will only do odds

As a user in the comment points out, sometimes not all keys may exist:

```
for i in zen:
    if (i%2 == 0):
         print(zen[i])
```

Another, shorter way is list comprehension, it is a bit unusual however, as you really don't need the list.

`[print(zen[i]) for i in zen if i%2==1]`

Comment: the list comprehension solution is safer since youre only traversing existing keys. Should the dictionary miss any numerical keys, the first solution would error out

Comment: What does `len(zen)` do in this case? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `len(zen)` says how many pairs are in the dictionary, basically it iterates up until that point.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your keys are integers, you can iterate over the keys and drop those not of interest for you:

```
for key in zen.keys():    # iterate over all keys of zen
    if key % 2:           # if reminder of dividing by 2 is non-zero, this is True
        print(zen[key])   # print value of zen[key]
```

As a matter of fact, iteration over a dictionary iterates over its keys, hence:

```
for key in zen:           # iterate over all keys of zen
    if key % 2:           # if reminder of dividing by 2 is non-zero, this is True
        print(zen[key])   # print value of zen[key]
```

Now be aware that `dict` are actually not guaranteeing any specific order. So if you wanted the values to be printed order of numeric key sort:

```
for key in sorted(zen):
    ...
```

When we pass `dict` to `sorted()`, we get list of `zen` treated as iterable (i.e. sorted list of its keys).

You can do compact this a but by using a generator expression. If you want these sorted, you can sort place `sorted()` around the generator:

```
for key in (k for k in zen if k % 2):
    print(zen[key])
```

Or, if you wanted these sorted, you'd place `sorted()` around `zen`:

```
for value in (zen[k] for k in zen if k % 2):
    print(value)
```

---

Couple side notes:

Your example `zen` has a broken string literal: `'Special cases aren't special enough to the rules.'` If it includes single quotes, use double quotes on the outside (or escape that quote): `"Special cases aren't special enough to the rules."` or `'Special cases aren\'t special enough to the rules.'`. This next one is not syntactically incorrect, but would be flagged by a linter. Normally the left indent is aligned on beginning of the line text, not on a character later on that line (like `:`).

And of course it should be mentioned, this is a bit of an odd bunch of data. If this was supposed to be an indexed list, then a `list` would make more sense and be easier to use, because you could also slice. I guess if you knew there were no gaps in keys, worked with the sorted option, you could still to that (in this case assuming first key is odd), but that's a bit besides the point:

```
for key in sorted(zen)[::2]:
    print(zen[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

A even number `% 2` will return `0` , `False` so we can use `if i % 2` and all odds return a value that will evaluate to `True`

```
[print(zen[i]) for i in zen if i % 2]
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 odd.py
> Beautiful is better than ugly.
> Simple is better than complex.
> Flat is better than nested.
> Readability counts.
> Although practicality beats purity.
> ```